# Bitfield mask/operations with optional items

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit-fields, bitmask

I'm trying to find a way to handle several bitfield cases that include optional, required, and not allowed positions.

```
yy?nnn?y
11000001

?yyy?nnn
01110000

nn?yyy?n
00011100

?nnn?yyy
00000111
```

In these four cases, the `?` indicates that the bit can be either `1` or `0` while `y` indicates a `1` is required and `n` indicates that a `0` is required. The bits to the left/right of the required bits can be anything and the remaining bits must be `0`. Is there a masking method I can use to test if an input bit set satisfies one of these cases?

Comment: That reminds me of the bitwise domain described in [this paper](http://www.di.ens.fr/~mine/publi/article-mine-wing12.pdf)

Comment: Check my solution, it works with your masks right out of the box: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25455747/2583484

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely, but of course it depends on how you represent the "templates".

For example, say you represent them as a pair `(z, o)` where `z` has a 1 for every bit that is allowed to be 0 and `o` has a 1 for every bit that is allowed to be 1 (as in the paper I linked to in the comments). Then to test `x` against it you could do:

```
if ((x | z) == -1 && (x & o) == x)
    passes test
```

You could also represent the templates as a pair `(mask, bits)`, where `mask` is a mask of all bits that have to match (ie 0 means ?, 1 means a fixed bit) and `bits` is the values of the fixed bits. Then you could test `x` like:

```
if ((x & mask) == bits)
    passes test
```

That's in general. If your problem has a special form, as it does in your question, you could use specialized tests.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (using C/C++ notation):

```
(input & mask) == mask && (input & ~(mask | mask<<1 | mask>>1)) == 0
```